# What is the exact definition of propagation constant of a two-port network?

Tags: passive-networks

Wikipedia says that the **propagation constant** of a [lattice network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_network) is

$$\gamma = \ln\left[\frac{\sqrt{\frac{Z_a}{Z_b}}+1}{\sqrt{\frac{Z_a}{Z_b}}-1}\right]$$

Wikipedia [also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant) that "In the context of two-port networks and their cascades, propagation constant measures the **change undergone by the source quantity as it propagates from one port to the next**."

This definition is not particularly clear to me. What is meant by "**source quantity**"? As far as I know, for a two-port network, we can give a certain input current and a certain input voltage at one port and get an output current and output voltage at another port i.e. the output port. By *change undergone by the source quantity*, do they mean something like \$V_{\text{out}}-V_{\text{in}}\$ or \$I_{\text{out}}-I_{\text{in}}\$ or \$\frac{V_{\text{out}}-V_{\text{in}}}{V_{\text{in}}}\$ or \$\frac{I_{\text{out}}-I_{\text{in}}}{I_{\text{in}}}\$? The word "change" seems really vague to me.

Comment: I think it means that if the source is a voltage, then the voltage gets attenuated (per lumped section) by the same amount.

Comment: @Andyaka What do you mean by "voltage gets attenuated" and "lumped section"?

Comment: From one section to the next voltage gets lower by the same amount. A lumped section is one of several cascaded two port networks. \$\dfrac{Vo}{Vi}\$ is the same for each section.

Comment: @Andyaka So you mean \$V_{\text{out}}/V_{\text{in}}\$ is constant for each lumped section (two port network)? And \$V_{\text{out}}/V_{\text{in}}\$ is the *definition* of propagation constant?

Comment: No Vo/Vi is constant. see this better wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant - Ah you changed your comment LOL. Vo/Vi is half the story - the other half is the phase change of a signal or the delay of the signal.

Comment: Did I not answer your question?  Argh how old this is.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [2-port networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network) with a variety of different parameters sets.

If you define a 2-port with Z-parameters, then the inputs are the port currents and the outputs are the port voltages.

If you define a 2-port with Y-parameters, then the inputs are the port voltages and the outputs are the port currents.

You can also define hybrid (H) parameters that take V as input on one port and I on the other.

Or ABCD-parameters where the voltage and current on one port are taken as the independent variables and the voltage and current on the other port are the dependent variables.

Or S-parameters that take inward-travelling waves of a given characteristic impedance as inputs and get outward-travelling waves as outputs.

The source quantities are, presumably, the inputs to your 2-port model, for whichever type of 2-port model you are using.

But frankly, you're unlikely to ever see this \$\gamma\$ again. So just take it as a defined variable for explaining the particular type of network you're researching, and don't worry too much about  how it applies to other types of networks.

Answer (score -1):

> **change undergone by the source quantity as it propagates from one port to the next**.... What is meant by "source quantity"?"

It means the **impedance of the source**, but also **the medium** and the **load**, which all affect propagation **attenuation and phase changes**, where time delay is the rate of change of phase. Each has well defined impedance and admittance.

- For examples; Inductance has skin effects of the conductor which slightly changes the w/l ratio and PCB dielectric is also frequency dependent and reduces in the microwave band.

But the basics are;

(1)  \$~~~~~\gamma= \alpha + j \beta\$

**Propagation constant** **=** **Amplitude** or **Attenuation** (alpha) constant + **j Phase** (beta) constant (per unit length),  which are both dependent on frequency, (\$2\pi\$f = \$\omega\$) and Dielectric Constant \$\epsilon_r \text{ or } D_k\$

(2) \$\gamma_{(\omega)} =\sqrt{Z _{(\omega)}Y_{(\omega)}}\$

**Propagation constant** is also the **root mean product of the insulation [S] x conductance [Ω],**
defined by;

- **Admittance of insulation** ,Y(f or ω) and **Impedance of conductor** Z(f or ω)
  both  per unit (p.u.) length ,  where,

  - \$Z~[\Omega] =R~[\Omega]+j\omega L~ [\Omega]\$ is the series complex impedance of the conductor and,
  - \$Y~[S]=G~[S]+j\omega C~[S]\$ is the shunt or parallel insulation admittance in Siemens, S

To be clear, apart from theory, approximations and ideal components which do not exist in nature,

- **ALL insulators are dielectrics, and ALL dielectrics are insulators, but actual materials have effective series resistance, ESR(f) and shunt leakage resistance (f).**
  The ESR depends on the interface between dielectrics and conductors and air has very low ESR compared to most dielectrics but depends on the conductor or semiconductor and 1D,2D or 3D geometry
- Also, unintended capacitance is often called parasitic C, this is inversely due to gap between conductors and Dk between and is per-unit length.
- **All conductors have effective series inductance, or parasitic ESL** It is also dependent on geometry of the area of the loop or cancellation of ESL, by the very close proximity of the return path..

### other

**Propagation velocity = Group Delay amplitude and phase.**

- Questions for your education

  - why do electrons travel so slow compared to the speed of light? (hint:waves)
  - when can Phase Velocity be faster than the speed of light? (hint: eigenfrequency )

Group velocity is slowed by the inverse of the factor that phase velocity is increased due to \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}}\$

[Ref:  Wiki pages.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Propagation_constant)

***Opinion:**  The most important take here is that material properties affect all propagation, attenuation and phase shift. Source impedance being the most important. e.g. very low Zs for efficiency, low V regulation errors (e.g. AC grid, DC PSU's and Audio Amps)  and choose matched Z(f) to improve return loss or reduce echoes, ringing etc, when the rise time is fast enough relative to the delay. All insulation and conductors have non-ideal properties, which are also includes parasitic {inductance, resistance, leakage & capacitance) which are all frequency and geometry dependent e.g. length/width or OD/ID ratio for impedance ratio \$Z_{[\Omega]}=\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.
It's like Ohm's Law for source to load attenuation.  It is also relevant for the 3rd material group, **semiconductors** and the 4th group , **plasma**.*

***The accuracy of any simulation is only limited by your imagination and the accuracy of your assumptions.***

If you can imagine it, you can simulate it. T.S.

Comment: any specific reason to post a second answer instead of editing or is it just a mishap?

Comment: A second answer nulls  the ratchet effect of down voters who are too lazy to to make a comment or reverse a DV with an UV.  @ChristianB.